# Populating GridLayout from code doesn't give same result as XML

Tags: android, grid-layout, cardview

I'm trying to replicate the following XML in code:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/row2Grid"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_rowWeight="40"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
    android:padding="0px"
    android:rowCount="2"
    >

    <!-- Box 1 -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#00ff00"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_rowWeight="8"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="6"

        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Box 2 -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_rowWeight="8"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="6"

        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>
```

The above looks like this, which is what I want:

[image: XML result]

First of all the GridLayout with id `row2Grid` will remain as XML. However Box 1 and Box 2 won't, so they have to be generated by code and added to `row2Grid` dynamically

For that I created this function which is called twice inside MainActivity's onCreate function:

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        ...
        generateBox("#ff0000");
        generateBox("#00ff00");
        ...
    }

```
public void generateBox(String colorStr) {

    gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.row2Grid);

    int row2children = gridLayout.getChildCount();

    CardView cardView = new CardView(ctx);
    cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorStr));
    GridLayout.LayoutParams cardViewLayoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(0), GridLayout.spec(row2children));
    cardViewLayoutParams.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0,8.0f);
    cardViewLayoutParams.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0,8.0f);
    cardViewLayoutParams.height = 0;
    cardViewLayoutParams.width= 0;
    cardViewLayoutParams.setMargins(0,0, 12, 34);

    gridLayout.addView(cardView, cardViewLayoutParams);
    gridLayout.invalidate();
    gridLayout.requestLayout();

}
```

But it doesn't work and only produces the below result:

[image: Code result]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You know when you have struggled with a problem for hours, and then as soon as you ask the question you see the solution for your self?

I saw the solution as soon as i posted the question. This is ofcourse caused by the fact that i first do this:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams cardViewLayoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(0), GridLayout.spec(row2children));
cardViewLayoutParams.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0,8.0f);
cardViewLayoutParams.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0,8.0f);
```

When i create `cardViewLayoutParams` i specify the row and column attribute of the cardView in the constructor but override them right below it. Changing this to the following:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams cardViewLayoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
cardViewLayoutParams.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(row2children,8.0f);
cardViewLayoutParams.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0,8.0f);
```

Makes it all work as expected